# In objective-c what is the difference between creating a class in the same .h file by writing, and creating a new file as Objective-c class?

Tags: objective-c, class

I am a beginner in Objective-C. I was trying out basic Objective-C programs in Xcode5. I created a project, say Example1 in which I wrote a program with two classes, say `Class1` and `Class2` in the same .h file. I created the class - `Class1` by - File-->New File--> Objective-C Class (`NSObject`). That created this,

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
{

}

@end
```

The second class Class2 I created just by adding,

```
@interface Class2 : NSObject
{

}

@end
```

Now, when I create another class by creating a new file (Like how i did `Class1`), I get another set of .h and .m files.

My doubt is, what is the difference between using different classes in the same .h file and different .h files ?

Comment: When one of your class grows in its size you should definitely leave it in it's own .h .m files, you'll get more cleanier and manageable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ObjC is is traditional to give each class its own .h and .m, and to give these files the same name as the class. In most cases, this simplifies finding your way around the code. It is not required. You could of course put all you class definitions in a single .h; you could put your entire program in a single .m with no user headers at all. But it is traditional and is generally a good practice to split them up.

There are exceptions. Sometimes two classes are extremely related and are put together into a single header. A famous example is `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`, which are both defined in `NSArray.h`. Apple pushes this further with `NSCalendar.h` which which includes `NSDateComponents`. (Personally, I probably would have split `NSDateComponents` into its own header, but this is an example of differing opinions.)

In very large systems (like Cocoa), the number of header files can be a concern for compile-time efficiency, so there are certain pressures to merge header files that are extremely likely to be used together. It is rare for this to matter that much in moderate-sized projects. (And it doesn't actually matter that much in Cocoa either, since Cocoa headers are almost always brought in through pch, and now through modules.)

As a beginning programmer, I would err on the side of consistency. Just put each class into its own header, with a matching .m. As you explore more existing frameworks, you will gain better intuition about when merging classes into a single header might be appropriate. I almost never do it myself.

There is one other kind of merging that you may come across. It is legal to declare an interface inside of a .m file. This is useful for creating private helper classes. I've done that occasionally, but I almost always find myself regretting it and splitting the private class into its own files. It just gets too annoying to find the code when it's not in a consistent location. But, sometimes for tiny, private data classes, there is sometimes justification for defining them directly in the .m.

Answer (score 0):

normally each class has its own files .h and .m but nothing is stopping you from writing all classes in a single file if that is ok for you.

Comment: You should add some pros / cons of keeping them in 1 file.

Comment: Yes, can you please give examples for both situations ?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare two or more interfaces in the same file. the methods and properties of all interfaces except the main interface couldn't be reach from the outside world, Because you could implement only the main interface in .m file.